# Setting no_proxy in kubernetes cluster

Tags: proxy, kubernetes

I want to set http/https proxy in pods and pass these variables via environment. However, I need to set no_proxy as well. Which values should I put it to not break somethings in k8s-inside-communication? As far as I know, there are some default services as "kubernetes.default.svc".

Answer (score 1):

You could, as illustrated in [OpenShift Container Platform bug 1467776](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1467776), add `.svc` to `no_proxy` (as in [PR 4678](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/pull/4678/files))

> `.svc` domain was added into service env file after installation.

```
[root@qe-gpei-etcd-sc-master-1 sysconfig]# grep NO_PROXY * -r
atomic-openshift-master:NO_PROXY=.cluster.local,.svc,qe-gpei-etcd-sc-master-1,172.30.0.0/16,10.128.0.0/14
docker:NO_PROXY='.cluster.local,.svc,qe-gpei-etcd-sc-master-1'
[root@qe-gpei-etcd-sc-master-1 sysconfig]# docker info |grep "No Proxy"
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
No Proxy: .cluster.local,.svc,qe-gpei-etcd-sc-master-1
```